# Dictionary Compare Method says values are not equal even though they are identical

Tags: c#

I have a custom method to compare dictionaries and for some reason it is saying that two dictionaries are not equal even though they get inserted the same exact data.

Here is the method that I wrote that should compare the dictionaries. It is failing on the values part even though the values are identical when I print them out and compare them

```
        public static bool CompareDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary, Dictionary<string, string> otherDictionary)
        {
            if( dictionary.Count == otherDictionary.Count)
            {
                foreach (var pair in dictionary)
                {
                    string value;
                    if(otherDictionary.TryGetValue(pair.Key, out value))
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pair.Value);
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(value);
                        if (!value.Equals(pair.Value))
                            return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            } 
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Well the most basic problem you have is that if one dictionary has a key that the other doesn't, you still consider them equal as long as the keys that *are* in both have the same value.  That's...probably not what you want if you want to compare two dictionaries for equality.

Comment: @Servy thanks for for pointing that out. I did not see it but have updated it on my machine